# ¿Cómo editar un campo por medio de un ASPxComboBox situado dentro de un ASPxGridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, gridview, devexpress

Tengo una tabla llamada Libros y en ella hay una columna llamada "Editorial" la cual guarda el ID de una editorial ya registrada. Además, tengo un ASPxGridView y en él está la columna "Editorial", cuando el grid está en modo Editar, la columna "Editorial" muestra un ASPxComboBox en el cual se muestran los ID's de las Editoriales ya registradas. 
El problema es que cuando quiero modificar ese campo (por ejemplo, el ID de la editorial del Libro es 'Santi' y quiero cambiarla a la 'Edessa', solo seleccionándolo desde el ASPxComboBox) al darle clic a Actualizar, no lo hace, se queda el ID que está ya registrado y no cambia en nada.
Ayuda por favor.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español!! te invito a leer [ask] para que sepas como realizar preguntas y que así tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad, también te invito a ver [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que no estés cargando los datos de la página cada vez que haces `PostBack`, para ello, en el `Page_Load` añade un `if(!Page.IsPostback())` y pon dentro el código de carga.

Si ese no es el problema, envía el código del `gridview editing` para verlo